# dojo combo box select state full name but display state code

Tags: combobox, dojo

Here is what I want to achieve - display state code when selecting a state full name. https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/selects_using_stores/demos/ProgFilteringSelect.html

But why I couldn't make it work? Here are the dojo codes and the state.json file.

```js
             dojo.xhrGet({url: datapath,
                          handleAs: dataformat,
                          load: function (result) {
                              require([
                                  'dojo/store/Memory',
                                  'dijit/form/ComboBox',
                                  'dojo/domReady!'
                              ], function (Memory, ComboBox) {
                                 stateStore = new Memory({
                                      idProperty: "code",
                                      data: result.states.sort(function(a,b) {
                                          var x = a.name.toLowerCase();
                                          var y = b.name.toLowerCase();
                                          return x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0;
                                      })
                                  });

                                  var cboState = new ComboBox({
                                      id: 'usastate',
                                      name: 'usastate',
                                      style:{width: '100%', height: '35px', fontSize: '30px'},
                                      placeholder: 'Select a State',
                                      store: stateStore,
                                      searchAttr: 'name',
                                      autocomplete: true,
                                      onChange: function(value) {
                                          dom.byId('statecode').innerHTML = value;
                                      }
                                  });

                                  cboState.placeAt(dom.byId('state')).startup();
                                 
                              });
                          }
                      });
```

```html
"states": [
        {
            "name": "Alabama",
            "abbreviation": "AL",
            "code": "01"
        },
        {
            "name": "Alaska",
            "abbreviation": "AK",
            "code": "02"
        },
        {
            "name": "Arizona",
            "abbreviation": "AZ",
            "code": "03"
        },
        {
            "name": "Arkansas",
            "abbreviation": "AR",
            "code": "04"
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

FilteringSelect worked. Not sure why Combo Box doesn't support it.

```js
         var cboState = new FilteringSelect({
                                      id: 'usastate',
                                      name: 'usastate',
                                      style:{width: '100%', height: '35px', fontSize: '30px'},
                                      placeholder: 'Select a State',
                                      store: stateStore,
                                      searchAttr: 'name',
                                      autocomplete: true,
                                      onChange: function(value) {
                                          dom.byId("statecode").innerHTML = value;
                                          dom.byId("statename").innerHTML = this.get("displayedValue");
                                      }
                                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the value of the HTML `input` element which should not be done here. Set the `displayedValue` attribute of the `ComboBox` in your `onChange` function.

```
var cboState = new ComboBox({
                id: 'usastate',
                name: 'usastate',
                style:{width: '100%', height: '35px', fontSize: '30px'},
                placeholder: 'Select a State',
                store: stateStore,
                searchAttr: 'name',
                autocomplete: true,
                onChange: function(value) {
                    this.set('displayedValue', value);
                    }
          });
```

Comment: Thanks Himanshu for your reply. I couldn't make it work using Combo Box. FilteringSelect worked.